# libevent - event_base_loop() should it get events repeatly?

Tags: c, linux, libevent

Here is a simple program using `libevent` on linux, it tracks the `stdout` fd, when it's writable, the callback will print some info to `stdout`.

---

### Code

**hello_libevent.c:**

```
// libevent hello
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/thread.h>


void event_callback(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg) {
    if(events | EV_WRITE) {
        write(fd, "hello\n", 7);
    }

    sleep(1);
}

int libevent_test() {
    int opr;

    // enable pthread
    if(evthread_use_pthreads() == -1) {
        printf("error while evthread_use_pthreads(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    // create event_base
    struct event_base* eb;
    if((eb = event_base_new()) == NULL) {
        printf("error while event_base_new(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    // create event
    int fd_stdout = fileno(stdout);
    struct event* event_stdout;
    event_stdout = event_new(eb, fd_stdout, EV_WRITE, &event_callback, NULL);

    // add event as pending
    struct timeval timeout = {10, 0};
    if(event_add(event_stdout, &timeout) == -1) {
        printf("error while event_add(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    // dispatch
    if((opr = event_base_loop(eb, EVLOOP_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
        printf("error while event_base_dispatch(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    } else if(opr == 1) {
        printf("no more events\n");
    } else {
        printf("exit normally\n");
    }

    // free event
    event_free(event_stdout);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    return libevent_test();
}
```

**Compile:**

> gcc -Wall hello_libevent.c -levent -levent_pthreads

**Execution result:**

```
hello
no more events
```

---

### Questions:

- In the test, event only occur once, is that the expected behavior? Or it should loop to get more event until timeout?
- How to make it get event continuously? Is it necessary to call `event_base_loop` within a loop, while it's already a `loop`?

Comment: Have you read this [reference](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html)

Comment: @SelçukCihan Just read it, and I updated the question, can u help with that?

Comment: Regarding your first question, yeah it will be removed after it has been processed (occurred), that is fairly reasonable i believe. As for the second question, a return value of one is also success in a sense because it indicates everything went well, however there are no more events pending.

Comment: If you do not want to loop yourself, try to set EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY and that way libevent loop will not exit even if there are no pending events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the event flag `EV_PERSIST` mentioned in [event.h File Reference](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#a3c4947a60eb6d09327c61f89135f9f37) might help.

> Persistent event: won't get removed automatically when activated.
>
> When a persistent event with a timeout becomes activated, its timeout is reset to 0.

Instead of

```
//...
event_stdout = event_new(eb, fd_stdout, EV_WRITE, &event_callback, NULL);
//...
```

you can pass this flag to [event_new](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#ab9a66f828d205eda84b321e32014cbbd)

```
//...
event_stdout = event_new(eb, fd_stdout, EV_WRITE|EV_PERSIST, &event_callback, NULL);
//...
```

and the other parts of code remain unchanged. At this time you create and add an event once and there's no need to call event_base_loop within a loop.
The compiled program just keeps printing lines of "hello" until it is terminated.

By the way, I noticed that changing

```
write(fd, "hello\n", 7);
```

into

```
write(fd, "hello\n", 6);
```

eliminates the leading character '\0' of each line.

Comment: Yeah, it indeed solved the issue as described. And seems `\0` is needed only when represent a string in memory, not in a file.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html it looks like you can call `event_base_loop` or `event_base_dispatch` from within a loop.

``` while (1) {
     /* This schedules an exit ten seconds from now. */
     event_base_loopexit(base, &ten_sec);``
     event_base_dispatch(base);
     puts("Tick");
  } ```

The main purpose of events is to inform some busy thread about some event that happened elsewhere. So, this looks logical.